# C2027: Как правильно настроить композицию классов?

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++

Есть 6 файлов:

- game.h - заголовок, в котором описаны подключения других заголовков.
- game.cpp - файл, содержащий главную функцию

---

- Room.h - заголовок, содержащий описание класса Room
- Room.cpp - файл, содержащий **ТОЛЬКО** подключение своего класса: `#include "Room.h"`

---

- House.h - заголовок, содержащий описание класса House
- House.cpp - файл, содержащий **ТОЛЬКО** подключение своего класса: `#include "House.h"`

Проблема заключена в том, что если удалить исполняемые файлы (*.cpp) этих двух классов (Room и House), то программа работает корректно. Иначе же появляется такая ошибка:

> Ошибка C2027 использование неопределенного типа "Room"
>
> [D:\Projects\Visual Studio\Test-CPP\Test-CPP\House.h: 16]

---

**Вопрос:** Как правильно сделать композицию дополняющих один другого классов? 
(Просто такая архитектура у меня была бы не одна.В исполняемых файлах я планировал писать определения будущих функций, чтобы сильно не нагружать заголовочные. Да и вообще как тогда сделать композицию таких файлов?)

---

Прилагаю код самих этих файлов (файлы Room.cpp и House.cpp будут в конце списка)

```
// game.h
#ifndef _GAME_H__
#define _GAME_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Room.h"
#include "House.h"

#endif // ! _GAME_H__
```

---

```
// game.cpp
#include "game.h"

int main(void)
{
    House Gomden(0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

```
// Room.h
#ifndef _ROOM_H__
#define _ROOM_H__

#include "game.h"

class Room
{
public:
    Room(unsigned int id)
        : m_id{ id }
    {
        std::cout << "Room #" << id << " was successfully generated!" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Room() { }

private:
    unsigned int m_id;
};

#endif // !_ROOM_H__
```

---

```
// House.h
#ifndef _HOUSE_H__
#define _HOUSE_H__

#include "game.h"

class House
{
public:
    House(unsigned int id)
        : m_id{ id }
    {
        std::cout << "House #" << id << " was successfully generated!" << std::endl;

        unsigned int rooms = rand() % 3 + 1; // 1 .. 3
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rooms; i++)
            m_rooms.push_back((class Room)(i)); // <-- здесь есть ошибка, 16 строка
    }

    ~House() { }

private:
    unsigned int m_id;

    std::vector<class Room> m_rooms; // <-- здесь нет ошибки
};

#endif // !_HOUSE_H__
```

А теперь 2 самых интересных на мой взгляд файла:

```
// Room.cpp
#include "Room.h"
```

---

```
// House.cpp
#include "House.h"
```

---

Классы работают верно в двух случаях:

1. когда удалены Room.cpp и House.cpp из проекта.
2. когда все находится в одном файле:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   class Room
   {
   public:
       Room(unsigned int id)
           : m_id{ id }
       {
           std::cout << "Room #" << id << " was successfully generated!" << std::endl;
       }

       ~Room() { }

   private:
       unsigned int m_id;
   };

   class House
   {
   public:
       House(unsigned int id)
           : m_id{ id }
       {
           std::cout << "House #" << id << " was successfully generated!" << std::endl;

           unsigned int rooms = rand() % 3 + 1; // 1 .. 3
           for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rooms; i++)
               m_rooms.push_back((class Room)(i));
       }

       ~House() { }

   private:
       unsigned int m_id;

       std::vector<class Room> m_rooms;
   };

   int main(void)
   {
       House Gomden(0);

       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```

Вывод:

`House #0 was successfully generated!
 Room #0 was successfully generated! 
 Room #1 was successfully generated! 
 Room #2 was successfully generated!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим:

В game.h перед подключением классов добавил прототипы классов:

```
class House;
class Room;

// затем идет подключение:
#include "Room.h"
#include "House.h"
```

Для реализации классов (Room.cpp и House.cpp) осталось так:

```
#include "game.h"

// реализация классов
```